# Getting this error while adding user "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I need to add users into AD got these permissions.
[image]

But I am getting these issue.

[image]

Users fetching is working fine. Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Sure will check the logs for this, can you also please share which query you are using.

Comment: I am trying to add user into active direcdtory using graph API

Comment: which type of users you are trying to add, Is this a new issue or has it worked before? please check this document for more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-create-a-user

Comment: I am writing for the first time(new issue). Could you please tell me what are the permissions needed for create new user.

Comment: Sure these are the permissions required to create a new user with respect to which permissions you are using which is either Application or Delegated permissions:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: I have User.ReadWrite.All permission for delegated

Comment: Can you please try and repo and see if you are still facing the same issue and share me the new query details, Thanks.